# How To Pass A Value To Every Twirl Template Implicitly

Tags: scala, playframework

In my play app, I have some action filter that does some auth stuff. It has a WrappedRequest type which includes some information after the auth has been done e.g.

```
case class User(f : Foo) extends  extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
```

I have a lot of twirl templates where I want to pass this `Foo` in. The way I am doing it now is to create an implicit value inside each controller method which loads a template, so e.g.

```
def doStuff : Action{

implicit request =>

   implicit val value = request.f

   Ok(some_template())

}
```

In the template I have

```
// some imports

@()(implicit f : Foo)
```

Because I have a shed load of templates, I will have to declare the implicit in my controller method and then update each template to have that implicit picked up. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: We use a similar method to pass things to every template. It was a bit tedious during the initial implementation, but it's just habit now. Would be interested if there's a simpler way.